# how to get Directory information in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to get all folder information of root directory in C#.

Comment: *Which* root directory? I can think of at least three things you might mean by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class or any other in the System.IO namespace.

For navigating through folders in ASP.NET make use of `Server.MapPath("/myfolder")`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sample:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~"));
```